# How to link mapStateToProps to two classes in the same React Native component

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have two classes in my react native component the first es without export so it's just a class the second is with export default. And then have mapStateToProps it's linked to the second class and it works fine but now I want to link the first class also because this.props.dipatch is not working . Have you any solution? Here is my code :

```
         import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import {
         TouchableOpacity ,
         View,
        BackHandler,
        Image,
        Text,
        Button,

        Platform,

           } from 'react-native'; 

         import {connect } from 'react-redux'

            class HeaderBarWebView extends Component{
             constructor(props){

       super(props);
         }

        goCamera(){

        this.props.dispatch(changeCurrentPage("camera"))
          }

    render(){
   return(

    <View>

   <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center',display:  'flex'}} 
     onPress={this.goCamera}>
    <Image
    style={{tintColor:"white" , height:30,
  width:30,marginRight:20}}
   source={require('../resource/img/camera.png')}
      />
   </TouchableOpacity>   

     </View>
         )}}

     class WebviewApp extends Component{

     constructor(props)
     {

   this.state={}
   this.goCamera= this.goCamera.bind(this)
     goCamera(){

    this.props.dispatch(changeCurrentPage("camera"))
               }
    render()
     {
      return(
      <View style={{flex:1,width:"100%"}}>
            <Button title="Press me" onPress={this.goCamera}></Button>

       <CustomWebView
       ...........................
      />

      </View>
       );
     }
        }

   const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  page:state.router.page,


                })
 const WebviewAp = connect(mapStateToProps)(WebviewApp)
     export default WebviewAp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also connect the first class just like second class

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(HeaderBarWebView);

const WebviewAp = connect(mapStateToProps)(WebviewApp);
export default WebviewAp;
```

But the batter way you should create new files for all separate component and use with import and export logic.